# Can't continue "The Only Cure" quest after inhaling the incense fumes at the shrine and talking to Kesh

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I reached level 12, I headed directly to the Shrine to Peryite and met Kesh. I gave him all the ingredients for the incense, and I inhaled the smoke, but when I asked him about the incense, I had only two options with a dead end. I can't move my hero, and I get the same two options over and over again. How can I continue my quest? Kesh isn't asking me to do the quest:

Maybe I'm not good enough?

Comment: There does appear to be a glitch with this if you talk to Kesh while he is creating the incense.  Did you do this?  Can you reload from a slightly earlier save?  You might be able to fix this via the console, but I'll leave that to someone who has more experience in that than I.

Comment: @agent86: I can reload but it doesn't help. There is a blue animal (ghost) when I'm stoned but I can't move and nothing happens.

Comment: I would suggest reloading, visiting the shrine, then leaving for over 30 days and coming back so it resets. Maybe that will fix the bug.

Comment: @agf: But I don't get this option about quest like in the youtube? It shows only the 2 start questions.

Answer (score 5):

UESP [describes](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Only_Cure#Bugs) the following possible causes:

> - If you talk to Kesh while he is creating the incense, you may not get the next quest update.
>
>   - (PC Only) This bug is fixed by version 2.0.4 of the Unofficial Skyrim Patch.
>   - (PC) Use the console command `setstage da13 21` to bypass Kesh not creating the incense.
>   - Try killing Kesh and looting the four ingredients back from his body. Once Kesh is dead, you should be able to activate the cauldron yourself and continue the quest as normal.
> - Cancelling while talking to Peryite may cause you to get stuck when he is finished, as you cannot move or select anything once you have inhaled the incense.

If you are using the PC version of Skyrim, you can bypass the *entire interaction* with `setstage da13 40`. If you do this, then you won't receive any dialog from Peryite at all, and can go directly to killing Orchendor. If you have not yet received the "inhale the fumes" objective in your quest journal, then you should do `setstage da13 21` and try to finish the quest normally *before* skipping the rest of the scene. Otherwise, you might have problems with turning the quest in at the end.

For Special Edition users, I would recommend downloading the unofficial patch, as it is available for all platforms and will (probably) fix this problem. Unfortunately, some unofficial patch fixes require a new game, but I'm not sure whether this is one of them.

Answer (score 3):

Have you got the quest from a "afflicted refuge" I think this may be your problem, because he is the quest giver. So maybe it glitched because of that. I think you can find him wandering around on roads "I found him near whiterun".

I guess you could also try reloading before you do the stuff for kresh. Other then that, im not sure.